# Using button from another file

Tags: javascript, html

Good day! I'm new to web development and still studying.
I'm trying to create a simple counter using javascript.

index.html

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<h1>Count </h1> 
<p id="count">0</p>
<button onclick ="mycounter()">Add Count</button>
```

test.js

```
var counter = 0;
function mycounter(){
counter = counter + 1;  
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = counter;}
```

Now this code works perfectly fine. Is it possible to transfer that button to another html file and everytime that button is clicked from the other file, the count display on my index is updated?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by  `other file`?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov the button is currently on my index page. I want to transfer that button to another html file and if i clicked the button, my count display on the index is updated. Is it possible? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @calwinalegre is this one-page application? if so you can store the value of the counter at a global level and re-use the same script in another HTML file.

or if the page refreshes after switching to another HTML file then you can store it in local storage.

Comment: @Abhishek No. I want to use 2 html files. 1 one for the button that increments and the other one is for the display. I'm trying something out. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer part of your html in to another file and use it in a separate file, that is called templating. The usual pattern is to load the contents of the "other" file via [XHR](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and add it to the DOM.

```
function loadDoc() {

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("buttonholder").innerHTML = this.responseText;

    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```